# Gedit folding plugin

Tags: gedit, gedit-plugin

I am looking folding plugin for gedit. I tried [gedit-folding](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/), but it did not satisfy me. Maybe that tells something.

Answer (score 1):

for ubuntu10.04 work
http://github.com/mikecrittenden/gedit-folding/blob/f42b340daf82cfa5b7cf106f1be2df002fd1ea31/folding.gedit-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It's said to work: http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/